# Display full information from database on tooltip of gridview

Tags: asp.net

I want to display full faculty information from database 'FACULTY' on tooltip of gridview having only faculty name as column.
i.e on click of 'detail information' link, I should get full information of particular faculty.Can Please somebody help with code.

Comment: Put html of gridview in your question.

Comment: use ajax popup extender it will help you

Comment: Here is a [link which may help you](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/display-gridview-row-details-using-asp-net-ajax-popup-control)